# how to pass value using a variable in an URL while executing this URL by perl scripting

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute an URL through perl scripting. In that initially I am keeping some value in a text file and setting value in file as an argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<','output_perl.txt' or die "Failed: $!\n";
my $text1 = do {
    local $/;
    <$fh>
};
close $fh or die "Failed again: $!\n";


open my $i, '<','output_perl_1.txt' or die "Failed: $!\n";
my $text2 = do {
    local $/;
    <$i>
};
close $i or die "Failed again: $!\n";


open my $j, '<','output_perl_2.txt' or die "Failed: $!\n";
my $text3 = do {
    local $/;
    <$j>
};
close $j or die "Failed again: $!\n";
```

So when I am try printing the variable `$text1`, `$text2`, `$text1` the value stored in `output_perl.txt`, `output_perl_1.txt`,  `output_perl_2.txt` are getting reflected. That mean if I add below it works fine:

```
print $text1;
print $text2;
print $text3;
```

but I am running one URL in which I want want to pass the value of `$text1/2/3`:

```
use LWP 5.64;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://sms.apps.example.com/http/sendPlainText?$text1 $text2 $text3'
```

The URL is working completely fine but value is not getting passed. When the URL is getting executed we can still see `$text1` `$text2` `$text3`, but I sould have see the value what it getting printed by above command.

Answer (score 5):

Use double quotes to interpolate variables into a string.  When you use single quotes, the resulting string is literally what you typed.  This goes for variables as well as metacharacters such as `\n`, `\t`, etc.

Read more [here](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html).

Comment: thans for a lot you checking this, but I have tried ruuninthe url by putting double quote, but the script is now hiting with like "$text1" etc, could you please nevigate where do I need to put the double quote?

Comment: Read the link I posted; that should make it clear.  Put the entire string in double quotes, not just the variable names.